# Changing a value in a file using awk

Tags: bash, ksh

I have one properties file of the follwoing format (Say name of the file is oldProperties.properties)

```
group1.value1=Hello
group1.value2=World
group1.value3=BlaBla
group1.vlaue4=blabla2
```

Now I want to develop a script which changes a particular value in the properties file and create a new file. The script should take propertyName and newValue of the property as command line arguments.

```
changePropertyValue.ksh group1.value3 GoodBye
```

The result file (say newProperties.properties) should look like this

```
    group1.value1=Hello
    group1.value2=World
    group1.value3=GoodBye
    group1.vlaue4=blabla2
```

For doing this I have written these line of codes in changePropertyValue.ksh

```
property_name=$1
new_value=$2

old_properties=oldProperties.properties
new_properties=newProperties.properties

echo "" > $new_properties

cat $old_properties |  awk 'BEGIN{ FS="=";OFS="=" } {if($1=="$property_name") $2="$new_value"; print $0;}' >> $new_properties
```

I am launching this

```
changePropertyValue.ksh group1.value3 GoodBye
```

and now when I do grep on newProperties file I am getting old value i.e

```
grep group1.value3 newProperties.properties
output 
group1.value3=BlaBla
```

At the same time if I launch the awk command directly on command line its working fine i.e if I launch this

```
cat oldProperties.properties |  awk 'BEGIN{ FS="=";OFS="=" } {if($1=="group1.value3") $2="GoodBye"; print $0;}' | grep group1.value3

output is :-
group1.value3=GoodBye
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong while writing the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes around the `awk` program (`awk 'BEGIN...'`) prevent the expansion of `$property_name`. Change your `awk` invocation to this:

```
cat $old_properties |  awk "BEGIN{ FS=\"=\";OFS=\"=\" } {if(\$1==\"$property_name\") \$2=\"$new_value\"; print \$0;}" >> $new_properties
```

Note that the outer single quotes have been replaced with double quotes, and all the original double quotes have been escaped with `\`.

Comment: Ooops... forgot - you'll also need to put a '\' in front of the `$` for `$0`, `$1` and `$2` (but not `$property_name`). Edited answer...

Comment: Wow !! It worked thank you very much :)
I can not up your answer as I dont have 15 points yet...but thanks a lot !!

Comment: This can be improved by using awk's -v option to pass the shell variable, rather than interpolating the awk command and putting escapes everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to pass the value of `$property_name` as a variable to `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="=";OFS="=" } {if($1==pname) $2=newval; print $0;}' pname="$property_name" newval="$new_value" $old_properties >> $new_properties
```